# Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging - could not install package

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Im trying to install Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging
I got this error:

> Could not install package 'Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging 42.1001.0'.
>   You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile259', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Im try to change the target profile to 78 and nothing happend.

Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are trying to install this package into a PCL project. You can only install this package into a `Xamarin.Android` project as there are no targets for this NuGet package to install into a PCL.

There are two main ways of figuring this out:

1) Look at the "Dependencies" on NuGet

2) Download the `.nupkg`, extract, and look in the libs to see the Target Frameworks supported

In this case, only `MonoAndroid70` is supported. This is synonymous with `Xamarin.Android` targeting API 24 minimum.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging/

Comment: nuget should include an easier way of figuring this out.

Comment: I agree. I actually have asked NuGet to help out in this effort: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4051

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. Supporting and subscribed on the issue thread.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. So if i cant install this package into a PCL project, how can i use firebase with cross platform? (XAMARIN)
You have alternative option for that? I need it mainly for push notification based DB. Thank you again.

Comment: You would create an abstraction and use the platform specific packages. There's also Firebase packages on iOS as well. You may not be using forms, but the best documentation on IoC/DI is our forms documentation https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, and I am installing Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging package to Xamarin.Android project not on the portable class library.

I fixed it by deleting bin and obj folder restarting the visual studio and clean solution.

After that, it got successfully installed.